# How to implement a status bar in an ASP.NET application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, c#-4.0

I have a simple ASP.NET application which has one master page called MasterPage.master. In MasterPage.master I have a Label called `lblStatus`. I want to update the text of this label when certain events happen in the website and always display the latest status no matter which web page I am on in the site.

This is what I'm thinking of doing, but I'm unsure if this is the most elegant:

1. Create a new class file with the code to update session state `Session["status"]`
2. Call a method in this new class file to update Session state whenever something happens
3. In the PageLoad event of the MasterPage.master page, update the `lblStatus.Text` with `Session["status"]`

Questions

1. Should I use a `Literal` instead of a `Label`?
2. Would it be better to do it another way?

Thanks, here's my code so far in MasterPage.master:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" %>

<script runat="server">       
    public string StatusText
    {
        get { return ltlStatus.Text; }
        set { ltlStatus.Text = value; }        
    }    
</script>

<html>
<head runat="server" id="Header">
    <asp:contentplaceholder id="ContentPlaceHolderScript" runat="server" />
    <title>MooDB - </title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="frmMaster" runat="server">
    <div>        
        <asp:Menu ID="mnuNav" Orientation="Horizontal" runat="server">
        <.. removed for brevity ..>
        </asp:Menu>
    </div>
    <div>
        <asp:Literal ID="ltlStatus" runat="server" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm unsure of the next bit. Do I need to copy this code onto every page in my site:?

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<script runat="server">

    private void ChangeStatus(string newStatus)
    {
        ((SiteMaster)this.Master).StatusText = newStatus;
    }

</script>    

<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="contentMain" runat="server" ID="Main" >

    <... my page content ...>
</asp:Content>
```

Sorry I'm new to ASP.NET and I'm not sure what to do. What is SiteMaster?

Comment: The `Label` control represents the html element <label>.  The `Literal` control will write exactly what you set it to (so you can include html tags within them).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Answer to question 1:**

IMHO, it really doesn't matter. I would say it's cleaner to use `Literal` when you don't need a label pointing to a field of a form, but, well, most people use `Label` in every case. Or output text directly with `<% %>`.

**Answer to question 2:**

There is no need to use sessions for this. Instead, use `this.Master` to access the Masterpage directly. You can then update the value of the label from your page.

For example, do something like:

```
public class SiteMaster : MasterPage
{
    public string StatusText { get; set; }
}
```

and:

```
public class HomePage : Page
{
    public void ChangeStatus(newStatus)
    {
        // Remember to cast this.Master to the class you use for the masterpage.
        ((SiteMaster)this.Master).StatusText = newStatus;
    }
}
```

---

To answer your last questions:

> Do I need to copy this code onto every page in my site?

Yes. *Unless* every page inherits from a parent class which inherits from `Page` class.

> What is SiteMaster?

`SiteMaster` is the class *I* gave to my master page. It could be `Template`, `Global`, or *whatever you want*.

If it might be helpful, here's a full example of the thing:

[image: Class diagram]

File **Site.Master**:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Site.master.cs" Inherits="Demos.StackOverflow.MasterPages.SiteMaster" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Sample code for StackOverflow</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <a href="Default.aspx">Home page</a> | <a href="Products.aspx">Products</a>
    <div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div>
    <div id="Status">
        <%= this.StatusText %>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

File **Site.Master.cs**:

```
namespace Demos.StackOverflow.MasterPages
{
    using System;
    using System.Web.UI;

    // Here's my SiteMaster class.
    public partial class SiteMaster : MasterPage
    {
        public string StatusText { get; set; }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

File **PageWithStatus**:

```
namespace Demos.StackOverflow.MasterPages
{
    using System.Web.UI;

    // This parent class inherits System.Web.UI.Page. This avoids code duplication.
    public class PageWithStatus : Page
    {
        protected void ChangeStatus(string newStatus)
        {
            ((SiteMaster)this.Master).StatusText = newStatus;
        }
    }
}
```

File **Default.aspx**:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Demos.StackOverflow.MasterPages.DefaultPage" %>

<asp:Content ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="DefaultButton_Click" />
</asp:Content>
```

File **Default.aspx.cs**:

```
namespace Demos.StackOverflow.MasterPages
{
    using System;

    // Here, we inherits from PageWithStatus, not from Page.
    public partial class DefaultPage : PageWithStatus
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        protected void DefaultButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.ChangeStatus("Done!");
        }
    }
}
```

File **Products.aspx**:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="Products.aspx.cs" Inherits="Demos.StackOverflow.MasterPages.ProductsPage" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Buy" onclick="BuyButton_Click" /><br />
    <asp:Button runat="server" Text="Sell" onclick="SellButton_Click" />
</asp:Content>
```

File **Products.aspx.cs**:

```
namespace Demos.StackOverflow.MasterPages
{
    using System;

    // Here, we inherits from PageWithStatus, not from Page.
    public partial class ProductsPage : PageWithStatus
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        protected void BuyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.ChangeStatus("The product is purchased.");
        }

        protected void SellButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.ChangeStatus("The product is sold.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm a little confused and have updated my question with my code. Could you have a look?

Comment: wow great answer! I am not using code-behind files, however it works fine. There's one final feature I'm struggling with. When the products page is navigated to, the status text gets cleared. I need it to be persisted across pages and only changed if the status changes. However the text should always be showing with the latest status. What changes to I need to make to implement that? Thanks again for your detailed answer, much appreciated.

Comment: @Mark Allison: you're welcome. Persistence implies sessions. Or database. So finally you were right using sessions in your question. If you want to persist the status, change `PageWithStatus.ChangeStatus()` method to save (in session or database) the new status, and `SiteMaster.Page_Load()` method to load the saved value (if any). Don't forget to load the saved only only `if (!this.IsPostBack)`.