# Programmatically change background colour of some text

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I have implemented master pages using this example [How to implement a status bar in an ASP.NET application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4154467/how-to-implement-a-status-bar-in-an-asp-net-application). I have a property on my SiteMaster.cs inherited MasterPage called Environment. On my MasterPage.master I have this code:

```
<body>
    <form id="frmMaster" runat="server">
        <.. some content removed for brevity ...>

        Environment: <%= this.Environment %>
    </form>
</body>
```

What I would like to do is evaluate `this.Environment` and if it is "LIVE" then colour the background of this.Environment text red, and if it's "TEST" colour it yellow. How would I do this?

**UPDATE** I've just added this code to MasterPage.master

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblEnvironment.Text = this.Environment;
    if (this.Environment == "LIVE")
    {
        lblEnvironment.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    }                
}
```

The page loads, but the text does not get set, it's blank! Also the old text, that was populated is now blank too (I left the old code there for now). I also get a warning in Visual Studio:

> 'ASP.masterpage_master.Page_Load(object,
>   System.EventArgs)' hides inherited
>   member 'SiteMaster.Page_Load(object,
>   System.EventArgs)'. Use the new
>   keyword if hiding was intended.

**UPDATE2:** This is what I have in SiteMaster.cs

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI;

public class SiteMaster : MasterPage
{
    public string StatusText { get; set; }
    public string StatusTime { get; set; }
    public string Environment { get; set; }

    protected virtual void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!this.IsPostBack)
        {
            if (Session["status"] != null)
            {
                this.StatusText = Session["status"].ToString();
                this.StatusTime = Session["statusTime"].ToString();
            }

            this.Environment = Session["environment"].ToString();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using the `<%=` syntax to print out the environment (this is using `Response.Write`), consider using a server control like a `Literal` or a `Label`. As you want to change the background colour, this suggests styling (CSS), so a `Label` would be appropriate.

(A `Literal` is just a text placeholder and renders no HTML, whereas a `Label` (usually) renders the text inside `<span>` tags.)

So I would change your master page markup to

```
Environment: <asp:Label ID="environmentLabel" runat="server" />
```

In the code-behind, set the `Text` property of `environmentLabel` to `this.Environment`. At the same time, test the value of the evironment, and set the `BackColor` property of the label as appropriate (or apply a CSS class).

**UPDATE:**
For a master page, you just need one class, which will inherit from `System.Web.UI.MasterPage`. If you create this in Visual Studio and call it `SiteMaster`, you'll get 3 files:

SiteMaster.Master (the markup)
SiteMaster.Master.cs (the code-behind)
SiteMaster.Master.designer.cs (automatically generated/updated)

In the SiteMaster.Master file, you'll want something like this:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="SiteMaster.master.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.SiteMaster" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Label ID="environmentLabel" runat="server" />

        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

In SiteMaster.Master.cs, you'll need something like this:

```
using System;

namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class SiteMaster : System.Web.UI.MasterPage
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.environmentLabel.Text = "environment";
            this.environmentLabel.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
        }
    }
}
```

As the environment label is on the master page, any normal page (ASPX) using this master page will get the label displayed. Every time a page is loaded, the `Page_Load` event in SiteMaster.Master.cs will be called, and the text will be updated. You don't need to define the `MasterPage` class yourself, that's provided by the .NET framework.

You may want to improve this `Page_Load` method, either by using ViewState and therefore only setting the text if you're not doing a PostBack, or by disabling ViewState on the `environmentLabel` control.

Finally, you'll have one or more ASPX pages in your site, with something like this at the top of the markup:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/SiteMaster.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm1" %>
```

Comment: On which event should I set the BackColor? Problem is the `MasterPage` inherits from SiteMaster.cs and there is a `Page_Load` method on SiteMaster.cs. I can't have a `Page_Load` method in MasterPage.master AND SiteMaster.cs can I? This is where I'm getting stuck, thanks.

Comment: So you have a normal master page, and then a class inheriting from this, and it's *this* class you're using as the master page? I don't see why you wouldn't be able to have another `PageLoad` method, after all, you have these on normal pages and they inherit from `Page`. Do you get an error if you try this?

Comment: @Graham - I've updated my question, would you mind having a look?

Comment: @Mark - I guess your Page_Load method isn't being called. Does the compiler allow you to use the `override` keyword on the method declaration?

Comment: @Graham - when I try that I get `'ASP.masterpage_master.Page_Load(object, System.EventArgs)': cannot override inherited member 'SiteMaster.Page_Load(object, System.EventArgs)' because it is not marked virtual, abstract, or override`

Comment: @Mark - I'm not sure how you're using your SiteMaster class, but I would suggest marking the `Page_Load` method in your `MasterPage` class as `virtual`, then your `SiteMaster` class should be able to override it.

Comment: @Graham - the way I am using SiteMaster is fully explained in the link at the top of my question. I have tried using virtual in SiteMaster and override in the master page and the page now loads, however the label text is blank. One odd thing, if I close Visual Studio and then load it again, and run the app both fields get populated, but when I navigate away they return to blank again. :-/

Comment: @Graham - I have just added SiteMaster.cs to my question for your interest.

Comment: @Graham - thanks for your reply. I'm not using code-behind files. SiteMaster.cs was created because I wanted to extend the MasterPage class to store status and environment information and have this accessible from any page in the site. I'm even more confused now. :-/

Comment: @Mark - I don't think you'll be able to "extend" the MasterPage class this way. You'll either need to use the code-behind model, or presumably you can add C# code to the master page in a script block (as you can in a normal ASPX) - e.g. `<script type="text/C#" runat="server">`. You should be able to put the code I have in my SiteMaster.Master.cs file inside one of these `<script>` tags. Not 100% sure though.

Comment: @Graham - OK thanks for your help. I got it working with Shadow's suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

something like this..

```
   var preTag = @" <font style=""background:yellow;color:#ff0000;font-weight:600;""><b>";
   var postTag = " </b></font>";

   Environment: <%= ((this.Environment=="LIVE") ? (preTag + this.Environment + postTag) : this.Environment)   %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also move the code from Page_Load to Page_PreRender in MasterPage.master and it should work.. it was blank because MasterPage.master Page_Load overwritten the Page_Load of SiteMaster.Master thus Environment was never assigned.